# the meaning of word 'yoko'

Tags: meaning

I really like how the word "yoko" is pronounced, and I'll like to use it in my bussiness. I think that my bussiness will be named "yoko garage".

Do you know what yoko means? Does it have any bad or good meanings/concepts related to it?

Comment: Just for consideration: [some names starting with yoko](http://www.nihongoresources.com/nbrowse/%E3%82%88%E3%81%93?action=names&section=dictionaries&page=names&sub=&type=start&search=%E3%82%88%E3%81%93&nametype=0&submit=+search%3E+)

Comment: it means sunshine my mothers name is yoko and she is from japan

Comment: @user9865 Japanese has many homophones, so there isn't just a single meaning. You're probably referring to [陽光 - ようこう youkou](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E9%99%BD%E5%85%89&eng=&dict=edict&romaji=on). Note that both "o"s are long here.

Comment: See [yooko](http://jisho.org/words?jap=yooko&eng=&dict=edict&romaji=on), [yoko](http://jisho.org/words?jap=yoko&eng=&dict=edict&romaji=on), [youko](http://jisho.org/words?jap=youko&eng=&dict=edict&romaji=on)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yoko (横) is a fairly generic term meaning "side".

However, there are some less common, negative meanings associated with this word meaning "wrong", "invalid", "illogical", and "disorder". It also has a sense in which a prostitute to leave a client in secret to meet another man ("yoko ni iku"). And of course there are negative terms derived from this as well such as yokoshima meaning "evil" or "wicked".

Answer (score 3):

http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E3%82%88%E3%81%93&eng=&dict=edict

1. horizontal (as opposed to vertical); lying down;
2. side-to-side (as opposed to front-to-back); width; breadth;
3. side (of a box, etc.);
4. beside; aside; next to;
5. unconnected

Maybe? Where did you hear the word? Sure it's not yooko or some such?

Comment: Yes, I also thought of a girls name 'Yooko', like 'Yoko Ono'.